# Dynamically adding items to an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm having a problem with adding items to an ItemsControl.
This is my XAML page:

```
<ScrollViewer  Grid.Row="4">
    <ItemsControl Name="items">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="ContentControl">
                        <Canvas Name="canvas1" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RecordedTime}" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="7" Width="370"  FontSize="36"/>
                            <Controls:RoundButton Name="save" Canvas.Left="380" Height="58" Canvas.Top="6" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In my code behind I have an Event inside of it.

```
records.Add(new item { Item = date.Now.ToString() });

        items.ItemsSource = records;
```

All the variables are already defined.

the problem is that when the event is triggered many times, only the first time is added to the ItemsControl, others do not appear. 
So does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: What event? When does it get triggered? What is `records` type and where is it defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `records` as an `ObservableCollection`. Assign it once and for all to the `ItemsSource` property of the listbox, then use only your collection. You can do that for instance in the constructor of the page, after calling the `InitializeComponents` method:

```
public ObservableCollection<item> Records { get; set; }

// Constructor
public Page3()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Records = new ObservableCollection<item>();

    this.items.ItemsSource = this.Records;
}

public void AddItem()
{
    // Thanks to the ObservableCollection,
    // the listbox is notified that you're adding a new item to the source collection,
    // and will automatically refresh its contents
    this.Records.Add(new item { Item = DateTime.Now.ToString() });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very well. But would please explain to me what the difference between the ObservableCollection and a List in this matter (because I used a List in my method) also why assign it to the Itemsource in the constructer and not in the method even though both of them give the same resaults.
Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is a list with a notification mechanism. If you use a classical list, the `ItemsControl` will have no way to know that you've added a new element to the collection (unless you tell it manually). And I'm setting the `ItemsSource` property in the constructor because you need to do it only once. It could be anywhere, it's just that the constructor is a convenient place to make sure something is executed only once.

Comment: How can I bind ItemsSource to ObservableCollection in ViewModel?